# Weak Differentiability of Holder functions

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

Is it true that every Holder function is weakly differentiable? If not please give counterexample. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked functions like $x\mapsto|x|^s$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38751/a-holder-continuous-function-which-does-not-belong-to-any-sobolev-space) might help you. It is a interesting example and more than you need.